# Sum same named xml nodes

Tags: c#, xml

I have edited this little MSDN example https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/311530

And I have the following 2 XML's

**Book1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
<book1 id="1" />
<bookSum number="1" />
</catalog>
```

**Book2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
<book2 id="2" />
<bookSum number="1" specialAttribute="123" />
</catalog>
```

**C# Code**

```
XmlReader xmlreader1 = XmlReader.Create(@"C:\Book1.xml");
XmlReader xmlreader2 = XmlReader.Create(@"C:\book2.xml");

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(xmlreader1);
DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
ds2.ReadXml(xmlreader2);
ds.Merge(ds2);
ds.WriteXml(@"C:\Merge.xml");
Console.WriteLine("Completed merging XML documents");
```

**Merge.xml** (Book1.xml + Book2.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<catalog>
  <book1 id="1" />
  <bookSum number="1" />
  <bookSum number="1" specialAttribute="x" />
  <book2 id="2" />
</catalog>
```

**And the question is**

how to join

```
<bookSum number="1" />
<bookSum number="1" specialAttribute="123" />
```

into one line ?

```
<bookSum number="2" specialAttribute="123" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it this way and is working:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Book1.xml");
doc.Root.Add(XDocument.Load(@"C:\Book2.xml").Root.Elements()); // merged

var sum = doc.Descendants("bookSum").Attributes("number").Sum(t => int.Parse(t.Value));

var xElement = new XElement("bookSum", new XAttribute("number", sum));
foreach(var attrib in doc.Descendants("bookSum").Attributes())
{
     if (xElement.Attribute(attrib.Name) == null)
         xElement.Add(attrib);
}

doc.Descendants("bookSum").ToList().ForEach(t => t.ReplaceWith(xElement));
doc.Root.Descendants("bookSum").First().Remove();
Console.WriteLine(doc);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, but for deduplication I replaced
doc.Root.Descendants("bookSum").First().Remove();

with
int i = 1;
            foreach (var node in doc.Descendants("bookSum").Distinct().ToList())
            {
                if (i > 1)
                    node.Remove();
                i++;
            }